# How may I measure the time taken by the CLR in JIT compilation of a method?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, jit

Does the .NET framework provide us an API to approximately measure the amount of time taken by the JIT compiler in compiling a method?

At the present moment, I use a combination of the following, which, though helpful, is wanting for a more satisfactory and reliable method.

1. I write profile statements at the beginning and the end of the method and run it for the first time noting the time.

   Then I do it again and take note of the difference in execution time.

   However, this is only good for purely computational methods that are pure functions. Any kind of a side-effect is likely to skew these measurements one way or another.
2. I look at the performance counters under the heading **.NET CLR Jit**.

Comment: Yes.  Profiling is the job for [a profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230818(v=vs.110).aspx).  It has been done.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the source code for the Microsoft's CLRProfiler from [here](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/clrprofiler).

The profiler uses the JITCompilationStart/JITCompilationFinished methods for profiling, among others. You can check out the code and extend if required.

Comment: Thank you. Yes., silly me. Have been using the CLR Profiler for years, among other commercial ones. Hans' comment in the original question made me realize that I was missing the forest for the trees.